# SQL Query to Remove Double Quotes in PHP Script is Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my PHP script, I need to update fields to remove the double quotes in a particular column.  When I execute my query, the fields are not stripped of the double quotes.  I suspect that it has something to do with escaping the characters in the query.  The query below is what phpMyAdmin generated for me when I clicked "Create PHP" after successfully running the query in phpMyAdmin.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `TNDB_CSV2` \n"
    . " SET `Event` = TRIM(BOTH \'\"\' FROM `Event`)";
```

How can I change this to run in my PHP script instead of running it manually in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I suggest use REPLACE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to escape the slashes themselves so that they stick around when the SQL query is executed so I am suggesting you do it like so:

```
  $sql = "UPDATE `TNDB_CSV2` \n"
    . " SET `Event` = TRIM(BOTH '\\\"' FROM `Event`)";
```

I also got rid of the backslashes around the quotes

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for your help and suggestion... it worked like a charm.